# Mostrar el último registro de cada campo de una misma tabla

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

Buen día!. Estoy atorado en esto y quiero saber si se puede hacer. En una tabla de mi base de datos, los usuarios registran diferentes movimientos de llamados (campo: `Fecha_gestion`). Algunos de esos movimientos pueden tener un dato adicional (campo: `Fecha_compromiso`).

Necesito traer los últimos registros de cada cliente de cada uno de esos campos. Subo una imagen de un `View` para explicarme mejor. *Nota: esta imagen no es de la consulta LINQ que necesito hacer*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De acuerdo a la imagen, necesito traer el último registro de `Fecha_gestion` (29/08/2018) y el último valor no nulo de `Fecha_compromiso` (25/08/2018).

Realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
var query = (from g in _context.Gestion
                     join d in _context.Deuda on g.PersonalesDni equals d.PersonalesDni
                     where d.Tipo_deuda == "JUDICIAL" && d.Cancelo_Desasignada == false
                     && g.Fecha_compromiso != null
                     select new GestionEJ
                     {
                         Dni = g.PersonalesDni,
                         Apellido = g.Personales.Apellido,
                         Nombre = g.Personales.Nombre,
                         Fecha_compromiso = g.Fecha_compromiso,
                         Ultimo_pago = d.Ultimo_pago,
                         Resultado_gestion = g.Resultado_gestion,
                         Usuario = g.Usuario,
                         Fecha_gestion = g.Fecha_gestion
                     }).GroupBy(s => new { s.Dni }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.LastOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Con esa consulta me muestra la última fecha de compromiso (25/08/2018) con su fecha de gestión (08/08/2018)

Probe con `Union` pero me duplica los resultados en la Vista.

Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Para entender... necesitas obtener el último registro de cada cliente de acuerdo a su fecha de gestión pero al mismo tiempo la fecha de compromiso no debe ser nula.. eso?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Claro, sería obtener el último registro de fecha de gestión y el útimo registro de su fecha de compromiso. Me imagino que el problema radica que esos campos estan en la misma tabla y esa consulta me trae los últimos resultados de uno u otro campo, no de los dos.